# Python, matplotlib, scatter objects via the points set as attributes

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have objects which include a x-coordinate, a y-coordinate and some other information such as color:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10


class Point:
    def __init__(self, x_axis, y_axis, color, add_info):
        self.x_axis = x_axis
        self.y_axis = y_axis
        self.color = color
        self.add_info = add_info


points = np.empty([N], dtype=Point)

for i in range(N):
    points[i] = Point(np.random.uniform(0, 1), np.random.uniform(0, 1), 'red', 1) # only exemplary 'red' and 1 here
```

How do I scatter these objects, i.e. points, and for instance set the color of a point to red, if color == 'red'?

I am a beginner at working with matplot and so far what ever I tried resulted in syntax errors... Thanks!

Comment: you really should post the stacktraces that your code is causing...seeing the errors makes it easier to debug

Comment: Ok, I will do so next time, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.scatter` needs an array (or list) of x-coordinates and an array of y-coordinates. Optionally an array of colors can be set. With the given `Class`, the code could look like:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x_axis, y_axis, color, add_info):
        self.x_axis = x_axis
        self.y_axis = y_axis
        self.color = color
        self.add_info = add_info

N = 10
points = np.empty([N], dtype=Point)

for i in range(N):
    points[i] = Point(np.random.uniform(0, 1), np.random.uniform(0, 1),
                      np.random.choice(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'magenta']), 1)

plt.scatter([p.x_axis for p in points], [p.y_axis for p in points], c=[p.color for p in points])
plt.show()
```

[image: sample plot]

Although it is an interesting example to study how classes work, this
 way of storing single points is rather inefficient in memory use and time. 
It is not recommended when there are many points or when elaborate calculations are needed.

If desired, the class can also get a draw function. This gets really slow when there are thousands of points, but can show the concept with a few points. Also note that in Python, lists are seldom traversed with indices, but rather by directly iterate through the values:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x_axis, y_axis, color, add_info):
        self.x_axis = x_axis
        self.y_axis = y_axis
        self.color = color
        self.add_info = add_info

    def draw(self):
        plt.scatter(self.x_axis, self.y_axis, c=self.color)

N = 10
points = [Point(np.random.uniform(0, 1), np.random.uniform(0, 1),
                      np.random.choice(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'magenta']), 1) for _ in range(N)]
for p in points:
    p.draw()
plt.show()
```